# 301 Redirects using RegEx

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm not great with RegEx. I have an Ecommerce site moving from PD Shop to Woocommerce. I need to write 301s for the pages on the old site to redirect to its corresponding page on the new site. The problem is the url structure for site A is completely different than it is for Site B. Rather than doing it manually for thousands of products, I wanted to use RegEx, but I'm not even sure it can be done.

If anyone has any insight on how to pull this off, I'd really appreciate the help. I'd prefer not to do it one link at a time, but I can't see how.

**Old links are structured like this:**

www.domain.com/shop/item.aspx/item-name/id/

Examples:

www.domain.com/shop/item.aspx/sierra-saw/58/

www.domain.com/shop/item.aspx/duffle-bag-double-strap-olive/2206/

www.domain.com/shop/item.aspx/duffle-bag-side-zipper-black/2207/

**New links are structured like this:**

www.domain.com/product/item-name/

Examples:

www.domain.com/product/sierra-saw/

www.domain.com/product/double-strap-duffle-bag/

www.domain.com/product/double-strap-duffle-bag/

Comment: Note that your examples do not follow the stated pattern. the colour disappear and there isnt always a leading /product/. I disregarded them in my answer.

Comment: You're correct. They do not always follow a regular pattern. If they did, this wouldn't be such a challenge. The new site separates attributes such as color into options, whereas, the old site created each color option as a separate product.

Comment: You should check if you can match 90% of them with some pattern and then move the rest by hand. It's not always a good use of your time to automate everything.

Comment: Also as your question is stated, we can't provide you with a good answer. When should we add /product/ or not? Is cyan considered a colour or just blue? Why don't we mention zippers? How do we know these duffle bags have double straps?

Comment: It looks like what you've got is a map, and that you should search for its keys and replace by the associated values.

Answer (score 0):

You should match `www.domain.com/shop/item.aspx/([^/]+)/.*` and replace it with `www.domain.com/product/\1/`.

The matching pattern matches url starting with the common root (`www.domain.com/shop/item.aspx/`), groups their next path fragment (everything up to the next slash) and match the rest of the line.

The replace fragment just repeats the grouped path fragment next to the new common root.